# Nautilus won't switch desktops when opening a directory that is already open on another desktop - the dock icon just wiggles instead?

Tags: nautilus

To reproduce: open the downloads folder and switch to a new desktop. Then, open chrome and go to downloads. Try 'open in folder' on any of the downloads. Instead of switching to the desktop with the already open downloads folder, the files icon just wiggles. Is it possible to make it switch to the desktop with the open folder? or even open a new window instead of just wiggling?

The behaviour can also be reproduced by trying to open any folder that is already open in another window on another desktop.

Thanks to anyone who can assist!

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: please [edit] your post with details of your version of ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on Ubuntu 22.04, install the Gnome Shell extension [NoAnnoyance v2](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2182/noannoyance/) by bjoerndaase. Users of older Ubuntu versions can install the NoAnnoyance extension from the software center. This extension gives newly launched windows immediately focus.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.